# Javascript function requiring two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

javascript is completely new to me. I am a relatively inexperienced rails developer. I have implemented something in a rails 3 app called joyride, which is a jquery plugin and pops messages up for users giving them a "tour of the page". This is the script that runs the tour nicely when the page is loaded

```
:javascript
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
      modal:true,
      expose: true
    });
  });
```

That works perfectly. My problem is that I need it to run when a button is clicked rather than on loading of the page.

So I started with a simple button on the HAML page

```
%button#myBtn
  Lauch tour
```

That gives me my button. Then I wrote a function (forgive me its my first) to fire the code when the button is pushed.

```
:javascript
  var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
  myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    $("#joyRideTipContent").joyride({
      modal:true,
      expose: true
    });
  });
```

This is where it gets strange. The code works - on the SECOND click. Clearly something is being passed in the first time, and then executed the second time, but I am way out of my depth, can anyone help!

thanks

EDIT:

changed the code to this on advice, but same problem exists...

```
  $(function() {
    $("#myBtn").click( function()
      {
        $("#joyRideTipContent").joyride({
          modal:true,
          expose: true
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

EDIT: added a jsfiddle for anyone with time to have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/garethburrows/beonc06z/

Comment: You shouldn't mix vanilla Javascript with jQuery: use `$('myBtn').click(function(){..}` instead of `document.getElementById('MyBtn').addEventListener(...`

Comment: thanks, will learn from that. However making that change means it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I forgot a `#` to mean "by Id" in the search... but try to create a jsfiddle in order to allow us to test it

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/garethburrows/beonc06z/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $('#myBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#joyRideTipContent").joyride({
      modal:true,
      expose: true,
      autoStart: true
    });
  });
```

you're mixing jquery and classic js - not good.

Comment: @GarethBurrows: well, if you give me root on your server, I can try to fix it there )))) Otherwise, could you provide more info - error messages? jsfiddle snippet?

Comment: @GarethBurrows: after skimming through joyride source code, I'd guess you need to add `autoStart: true` to the options.

Comment: @georg I've added the setting to your post, that's the correct answer

Comment: Spot on @georg. That fixes it in my my jsfiddle so is clearly the solution. I appreciate I'm asking a lot, but how would you diagnose an issue with that setting, as it actually kills the script in my full app. The tour loads autmatically, but you cannot click through it or close it. I assume its conflicting with other jquery code. What tool woudl you use to diagnose the issue?